# Understanding moneky patched implementation of Pundit from Rails 3 to 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pundit

As part of this migration work I have been doing, I came across a monkey patched initialization of pundit. I'm understanding it for the most part but there is a part that is causing me errors:

```
module Pundit

  class << self
    def authorize; raise 'DoNotUseThisMethod'; end
    def authorize!; raise 'DoNotUseThisMethod'; end
  end

  included do
    if respond_to?(:rescue_from)
      rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized
    end

    if respond_to?(:helper_method)
      helper_method :authorize
      helper_method :can?
    end
  end

  protected

  ... 
  # authorize, authorize! and other methods defined
```

Error when bring the server up:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/concern.rb:126:in `included': Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern (ActiveSupport::Concern::MultipleIncludedBlocks)
```

I tried moving this module to the `concerns` folder, but if I do that, the `authorize` methods are not called.

The `Pundit` module I included on the `ApplicationController`.

Any ideas? I know I've had this error before and I've even described it here but in this time I'm not namespacing as the other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what this monkeypatch is really supposed to accomplish. But one way of avoiding the error is by not using ActiveSupport::Concern#included. Instead just use the actual Ruby hook ([Module#included](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-included)) that it abstracts away:

```
module Pundit

  class << self
    def authorize; raise 'DoNotUseThisMethod'; end
    def authorize!; raise 'DoNotUseThisMethod'; end

    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval do
        if respond_to?(:rescue_from)
          rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized
        end

        if respond_to?(:helper_method)
          helper_method :authorize
          helper_method :can?
        end
     end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks once again! I had to change `def included` for `def self.included`